# How to implement EXCEPT boolean operator of ISYS using Lucene API

Tags: lucene

I've studied that EXCEPT is a boolean operator for queries in ISYS(which is an Enterprise search Engine).It has the following functionality.
If this is the query First EXCEPT Second------>The retrieved documents must contain the first search term but only if the second term is not in the same paragraph as the first. Both terms can appear in the document; just not in the same paragraph.

Now how do I achieve this in Lucene?

Thank you :)

Comment: Lucene does not have a notion of paragraph out-of-the-box. Implementing it is possible, but may take some work.

Comment: You mean to say that there is no proper API to access paragraph,right? So there should be some way to go the position of the term in the document retrieved.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A rough outline of an implementation strategy would be to:

1. tokenize your input on paragraphs
2. index each paragraph separately, with a field referring a common document identifier
3. use the [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html)to construct a query that takes advantage of the above construction